# Why is JQuery .Resize() giving me trouble?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get the `content` div on my page to fix itself when a user resizes the page.  I have static divs on the top and bottom, making the `content` div the only one that resizes to flow with the page.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $("#content").height();
    newheight = (height-136)+"px";
    $("#content").css("height",newheight);
});
function test() {
    var height = $("#content").height();
    newheight = (height-136)+"px";
    $("#content").css("height",newheight);
}
```

I am subtracting 136px from the height so that it fits inbetween my two static divs.

On page load, I run the `test()` function, and it resizes the content div like it should.  But when I go to resize the window with the sizing handles it shrinks all the way down to the size of the content (only a couple words right now).

Here is the page itself live: [spynsycle.com/ttr](http://spynsycle.com/ttr)
(Ignore the ugly green, it is for debug purposes only)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't you want `$(window).height()`? Maybe I'm not understanding (entirely possible).

Comment: You were absolutely right! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @JaredFarris, you need to be taking `$(window).height()`. For example if you go to the site in Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug) and put the following in the console, it resizes perfectly as you want it to:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    newheight = (height-136)+"px";
    $("#content").css("height",newheight);
});
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Sorry for kinda stealing your suggestion - I was giving it some thought and part way through writing an answer when you posted it. If you want to post it yourself then the OP can mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you at least mentioning it.